# macro \newcommand{mymacro}{option=value} fail in a tcolorbox environment

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I'm trying to put a option through another macro in a tcolorbox environment like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\tcboption}{colback=blue}
\newcommand{\bubble}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
      \tcboption]
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\bubble{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
\end{document}
```

that doesn't work, it says:
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/colback=blue' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
This might be a common mistake but so far i've found no solution, even in #latex in freenode.

**UPDATE**
here i upgrade my example to something closer to my real macro. Following is one of the solution provided by others put in practice into it.

```
\usepackage{xargs}
%[ ... ]
\newcommand{\myoption}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{line}}{%
  skin=enhanced, finish={\draw[blue, thin,-] (0,0) -- +(0,-10); }, }{}
}

\newcommandx{\bubblex}[4][1=20em, 2=, usedefault]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      width=#1,
      \myoption{#2}, title=3,fonttitle=\bfseries]
    #4
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

Solution:

```
\tcbset{
  tcboption/.style={skin=enhanced, finish={\draw[blue, thin,-] (0,0) -- +(0,-10); }},
}

\newcommandx{\bubblex}[4][1=20em, 2=, usedefault]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      width=#1,
      #2, title=3,fonttitle=\bfseries]
    #4
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\bubble[][tcboption]{\lipsum[1][1-2]}

\end{document}
```

It works even when when i leave the the second optional arg. of \bubblex empty, which is what i wanted. I though the comma after #2 in the macro definition would cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use macros expanding to options. But you can use *styles*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{myoption/.style={colback=blue!20}}
\newcommand{\bubble}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[myoption]
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\bubble{\lipsum[1][1-2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
  tcboption/.is choice,
  tcboption/line/.style={skin=enhanced, finish={\draw[blue, thin,-] (0,0) -- +(0,-10); }},
  tcboption/back/.style={colback=blue!20},
}
\newcommand{\bubble}[2][]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[#1]
    #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\bubble[tcboption=back]{\lipsum[1][1-2]}

\bubble[tcboption=line]{\lipsum[1][1-2]}

\end{document}
```

You can also combine the two by using `tcboption=line,tcboption=back`.

Comment: yes it seems to work but in a very limited context. For example, if it is one option among many in \bubble[2] ...{tcolobox}[myoption, title=title] and that i want to put like this \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{colourise}}{myoption, }{} title=...   This does not work

Comment: @user1850133 Sorry, but I can only answer what's asked. Please, make a new question with as much details as needed to clearly understand your aim. And the problem is most likely solved with styles and not via macros.

Comment: my real macro (named tcboption instead of myoption for this exemple) was rather like this: \newcommand{\tcboption}[1][]{ \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{line}}{skin=enhanced,
  finish={\draw[blue, thin,-] (0,0)  -- +(0,-10); }, }{}
} Note the comma at the end of the 'finish' definition.

Comment: @user1850133 A command with an optional argument would not even work with wipet's approach and would bomb out.

Comment: @user1850133 I added a different version that you can try.

Answer (score 2):

You must expand the parameter before `\begin{tcolorbox}` is processed. I don't know how but it is fact.

```
\def\tcboption{colback=yellow}
\def\bubble#1{%
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\begin{tcolorbox}[\tcboption]}\tmp
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to see how `\expandafter` can be applied for obtaining `\tcboption`'s toplevel-expansion you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\tcboption}{colback=blue}
\newcommand{\bubble}[1]{%
    \expandafter\begin\expandafter{\expandafter t\expandafter c\expandafter o%
    \expandafter l\expandafter o\expandafter r\expandafter b\expandafter o%
    \expandafter x\expandafter}\expandafter[\expandafter{\tcboption}]%
    #1%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\bubble{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
\end{document}
```

Shorter is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand{\tcboption}{colback=blue}
\newcommand{\bubble}[1]{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter[\expandafter{\tcboption}]}{\begin{tcolorbox}}%
    #1%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\bubble{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
\end{document}
```

Both examples are for demonstration-purposes only and are focussed at obtaining only the toplevel-expansion of `\tcboption`.

wipet's approach leads to expanding everything that comes from `\tcboption` until remaining tokens are either unexpandable or were not expanded due to `\unexpanded`/`\noexpand` being provided or due to being defined in terms of `\protected`.

Except that with LaTeX I'd probably use `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef` I prefer wipet's approach to my two examples.

The "royal road" in this matter, namely the defining of styles, has been shown by egreg.